# UWP Webview - How to download a file generated in Javascript

Tags: javascript, webview, download, uwp, blob

I'm developing an application in React Native which uses some windows native components. One of those components is a WebView.

I'm showing a website via this WebView and this website records the camera video and prompts the user to download the file (it's a file created from a `Blob` and `URL.createObjectURL(blob)`). However, the WebView does not open any folder picker or file picker, and the user cannot save the file.

Here is my WebView code (remember it has some properties of React Native):

```
using ReactNative.UIManager;
using ReactNative.UIManager.Annotations;
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace ListProject.CustomModules
{
    public class PremissionWebviewViewManager : SimpleViewManager<WebView>
    {
        private Uri sourceUri;
        private WebView thiswv;

        public override string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return "PermissionWebviewViewManager";
            }
        }

        [ReactProp("sourceUri")]
        public void SetSource(WebView view, String source)
        {
            this.sourceUri = new Uri(source);
            thiswv.Navigate(this.sourceUri);
        }

        protected override WebView CreateViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext)
        {
            thiswv = new WebView();
            thiswv.PermissionRequested += HandlePermissionRequested;
            // thiswv.UnviewableContentIdentified += HandleDownloadContent; <--- I thought this could help, but I came up with nothing

            return thiswv;
        }

        private void HandlePermissionRequested(WebView sender, WebViewPermissionRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            args.PermissionRequest.Allow();
        }

        private void HandleDownloadContent(WebView sender, WebViewUnviewableContentIdentifiedEventArgs args)
        {
            // Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(args.Uri);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the React Native component:

```
render() {
    return (
        <PermissionWebview 
            style={{flex: 1}}
            mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
            domStorageEnabled={true}
            allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
            source={{uri: this.website}} 
            sourceUri={this.website} 
            allowFileAccessFromFileURLs={true}
            allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
        />
    );
}
```

And here the script used in JS on the website part to trigger the download:

```
var blob = new Blob(recordedVideo, {type: 'video/webm'});
var videoUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

var anchorTag = $('<a class="download_link"></a>');
anchorTag.attr('href', videoUrl);
anchorTag.attr('target', '_blank');
anchorTag.attr('download', 'video.webm');

// Add the anchor tag to DOM
$('body').append(anchorTag);

// We use DOM element and not JQ element to trigger DOM events (not JQ ones)
anchorTag[0].click();

// Remove tag once clicked and event triggered
anchorTag.remove();
```

The Windows app has all file capabilites granted in the manifest (though the user is not asked to let the app access the file system), and in a native Edge browser it works - so it's not an Edge API limitation (WebView uses Edge engine in UWP W10).

**How can I achieve so the download window is triggered and the file can be downloaded on the client?**

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please also show  the JavaScript module?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT done! Thank you!

Comment: found any solution?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, no. We had to discontinue the React Native app aproach and go through Electron encapsulated web one.